# Check if terminal output matches my string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to find if i have the right leptonica version installed. I run `tesseract -v` and the output is this one:

```
tesseract 3.04.01

 leptonica-1.73

  libgif 5.1.2 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.4 : libopenjp2 2.1.0
```

The output it's written on stderr, so my script looks like this:

```
if tesseract -v 2> >(head -n2 | tail -n1) | grep -q 'leptonica-1-73' ; then
    echo "matched"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

When I run the script, it shows:

```
Syntax error: redirection unexpected.
```

Any idea why?

Comment: @Igor Chubin thanks for editing my question!

Comment: You can most likely avoid the entire middle of that pipeline: `if tesseract -v 2 | grep -q 'leptonica-1-73'`

Comment: Do you start your script with `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` ? Process substitution is a bash feature. Also exists in ksh and probably zsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Use

```
tesseract -v 2>&1 | head -n2 | tail -n1
```

instead of

```
tesseract -v 2> >(head -n2 | tail -n1)
```

Comment: Worked just fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GEazy, please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235